# How to keep focus in css

Tags: html, css

I have this page with a header tag which include four buttons like `Home About..` but using focus I managed to have some changes in properties like border after I click one of them, but I want that button to stay clicked after I click any other element not in that navigation list, I also could make the `home` for example, to be selected by default, (look at `.nav a:first-child`), but also another problem came when I tried to remove those changes to give the focus to others. What is the solution to such a problem?.
Here is the css and related markup:

**CSS**

```
.nav{
    width: 1200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    min-height:50px;
    max-height:50px; 
    background: royalblue;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.nav a:first-child{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.nav a:focus{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**HTML5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YourWords</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="css/prostyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="nav">
            <a href="#" >Home</a>
            <a href="#">Best</a>
            <a href="#">Authors</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </header>
        <div class="wrap">
           ...
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
           ...
        </footer>
        <script src="js/principal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your nav items id's to make life easier. Then using jQuery

```
var $lastClicked;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".nav a").each(function() {
        $(this).click({param: this.id}, setLastClicked);
    });
});

function setFocus(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $lastClicked = event.data.param;
}

$(".wrap").click(function() {
    $lastClicked.focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I see you mean $(".nav"), but I want to remove the focus on home, because it is given by default.

Comment: I thought you want the focus to remain on the home link when any other non nav item is clicked? Ahhh, you want focus to stay on the last clicked nav item?

Comment: @TiyebBellal - you might want to run that through a debugger or jsFiddle, at work atm so can't test it but it should be there or there abouts

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

To make this useful, I solved the issue using the following CSS classes and javascript, also with IDs as @rory recommended:

**HTML5**

```
<header class="nav">
            <a href="#" id="home" onclick="app.hmclick()" class="modif">Home</a> 
            <a href="#" id="best" onclick="app.bsclick()" class="clearmodif">Best</a>
            <a href="#" id="authors" onclick="app.auclick()" class="clearmodif">Authors</a>
            <a href="#" id="about" onclick="app.abclick()" class="clearmodif">About</a>
        </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.modif{
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.clearmodif{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var app={
curfocus:document.getElementById('home')
, setmodif:function(cls){
    this.curfocus.setAttribute('class',cls);
},

hmclick:function (){
    app.curfocus.setAttribute('class','clearmodif');
    app.curfocus=document.getElementById('home');
    this.setmodif('modif');
},
bsclick:function (){
    app.curfocus.setAttribute('class','clearmodif');
    app.curfocus=document.getElementById('best');
    this.setmodif('modif');
},
auclick:function (){
    app.curfocus.setAttribute('class','clearmodif');
    app.curfocus=document.getElementById('authors');
    this.setmodif('modif');
},
abclick:function (){
    app.curfocus.setAttribute('class','clearmodif');
    app.curfocus=document.getElementById('about');
    this.setmodif('modif');
}
};
```

Thank you all.